# Como trabajar con Highcharts y Base de Datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

Intento mostrar información de la columna **total** de mi base de datos con el siguiente **DEMO**:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line/sand-signika

Esta es la tabla con la que quiero trabajar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como funciona. Es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con Highcharts, y no tengo idea de como implementarlo, porque al parecer con esta **DEMO** debo trabajar con **JSON**. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Normalmente Highcharts trabaja en el cliente. Para poder hacer llegar los datos desde tu Servidor/BBDD al cliente el último (cliente/navegador) tiene que hacer una petición al primero (servidor). Esto se puede hacer vía [ajax](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). En el ejemplo que pones usa JQuery para hacer esto. Existen muchas formas de hacerlo. Si pones código mostrando lo que has intentado recibirás más ayuda corrigiendo tu código o mostrándote alternativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En resumen, esto es lo que yo haria.

1. crear un controlador en PHP que te traiga los datos que necesito
   como un objeto.
2. Hacer un llamado por medio de ajax, de forma que consulte los datos que obtuve en el paso anterior, en formato json, y segun los necesite para la grafica.

Como recomendacion, empieza con algo facil, si quieres con datos "quemados", y vas ajustando tus scripts segun la necesidad.

Quedo atento. Saludos